# Active admin habtm filter with text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an association

```
  class School < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :standards
  end
```

In my active admin page for standards, I need to have a filter for schools with a text field for typing the school id. (Having a dropdown as schools filter is not feasible since I've thousands of schools in my db). I need something like:

```
  filter :schools_id
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this gem? I love it. 
https://github.com/holyketzer/activeadmin-ajax_filter

If what you want is to filter the standards index by schools, supposing your model association is bidirectional you can install the gem and try something like this:

```
  include ActiveAdmin::AjaxFilter
  filter :school, as: :ajax_select, data: {
    url: '/admin/schools',
    search_fields: [:id],
    static_ransack: { active_eq: true },
    ajax_search_fields: [:id], 
  }
```